# sqlite - how to escape semicolons in a string with two-single quote in an insert statement

Tags: sql, sqlite

[there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10728903/sqlite-how-to-escape-semicolons-in-a-string-in-an-insert-statement) is a similar question but not the same and can't solve my problem

My sql is like below:

```
INSERT INTO Table_A (ID, Query) 
    VALUES ('1', 'UPDATE Table_B SET ( text) = (''I am string'') where ID = ''1'';');
```

But I get

> unrecognized token: "'UPDATE Table_B SET ( text) = (''I am string'') where ID = ''1''":

However when I remove the `;` character, I have get no error message.
It seems that `;` cannot be used with two-single quotes `''`

So How can I make the above sql work?

Thanks

Comment: How is that update code being executed?  Note that if executing from something like Java or C#, you don't need the semicolon at the end.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen It will be run in a transaction using TypeScript

Comment: which version of sqlite you have used??it's may working [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=bacb68a29aae102b9974e3aa5941fa76)

Comment: @FrustratedDeveloper 3.11.0

Comment: @kt_at_kt . . . Your code is fine:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.8&fiddle=dd7d15d63dff25ef71c8a3c6b258653c.

Comment: @GordonLinoff but I cannot run in Mac, DB Browser for SQLite v3.9.1

Answer (score 0):

Could you maybe separate the semicolon literal part:

```
..., '... where ID = ''1''' || ';');
```

Comment: `INSERT INTO Table_A (ID, Query) VALUES ('1', 'UPDATE Table_B SET ( text) = (''I am string'') where ID = ''1''' || ';');` but still get `unrecognized token: "'": `